# Is it possible to change the Excel 'Page layout view' programmatically, using the office-js JavaScript library?

Tags: excel, office-js

Recently I started working on my Excel add-in using `office-js`. I am now in the process of generating a 'template' which adds a header and footer to the active worksheet. This all works fine, and here is the snippet how I achieved it:

```
await Excel.run(async (ctx) => {

    var myHeaderAndFooterObject = {
        leftHeader: 'leftHeader',
        centerHeader: 'centerHeader',
        rightHeader: 'rightHeader',
        leftFooter: 'leftFooter',
        centerFooter: 'centerFooter',
        rightFooter: 'rightFooter',
    }
      
    ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().pageLayout.headersFooters.defaultForAllPages.set(myHeaderAndFooterObject, false);
      

    await ctx.sync();
      
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

However, the problem is, that after I add the header and footer, I also want to display them to the user, which you can do manually by enabling the 'Page layout view' in Excel (by clicking the INSERT tab in the Excel ribbon and then the 'Header and footer' button). Though, I want to show the `Page layout view` programmatically after I added / changed the header and footer.

However, after reading multiple posts and documentation, I can't seem to find any way to achieve this. So hence the question, is this programmatically possible using `office-js`?